# Python TypeError: string indices must be integers on a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm having an issues. I have a dictionary, which I'm trying to make into a Dataframe, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
over_time_req_payload = {
    'req': json.dumps(interest_over_time_widget['request']),
    'token': interest_over_time_widget['token'],
    'tz': timezone
}

req_json_interest_over_time = requests.get(interest_over_time_url,
                    params=over_time_req_payload,
                    cookies=cookies,
                    headers={'accept-language': 'us'})

iot_trimmed = req_json_interest_over_time.text[len(data_trim):]

df = pd.DataFrame(iot_trimmed['default']['timelineData'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(dtype='float64'), unit='s')
df = df.set_index(['date']).sort_index()
result_df = df['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series( str(x).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(','))
```

I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
string indices must be integers
  File "C:\Users\rayko\DevProjects\googleExamples\auxilary_files\gTrendsUtil_simple_working.py", line 74, in <module> (Current frame)
    df = pd.DataFrame(iot_trimmed['default']['timelineData'])
```

Shouldn't the pd.Dataframe take my dictionary which comes from the json request, and then after I set the index and types, make thius useable so I can print the .head()

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I'm pretty mew at this so it might be obvious. All I've found online is the fact that I need to index the string, but the json returns a dict. Small excerpt below when I print just iot_trimmed.

```
{"default":{"timelineData":[{"time":"1604188800","formattedTime":"Nov 1 \u2013 7, 2020","formattedAxisTime":"Nov 1, 2020","value":[19],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["19"]},{"time":"1604793600","formattedTime":"Nov 8 \u2013 14, 2020","formattedAxisTime":"Nov 8, 2020","value":[21],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["21"]},{"time":"1605398400","formattedTime":"Nov 15 \u2013 21, 2020","formattedAxisTime":"Nov 15, 2020","value":[32],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["32"]},{"time":"1606003200","formattedTime":"Nov 22 \u2013 28, 2020","formattedAxisTime":"Nov 22, 2020","value":[36],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["36"]},{"time":"1606608000","formattedTime":"Nov 29 \u2013 Dec 5, 2020","formattedAxisTime":"Nov 29, 2020","value":[32],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["32"]},{"time":"1607212800","formattedTime":"Dec 6 \u2013 12, 2020","formattedAxisTime":"Dec 6, 2020","value":[24],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["24"]},{"time":"1607817600","formattedTime":"Dec 13 \u2013 19, 2020","formattedAxisTime":"Dec 13, 2020","value":[42],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["42"]},{"time":"1608422400","formattedTime":"Dec 20 \u2013 26, 2020","formattedAxisTime":"Dec 20, 2020","value":[41],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["41"]},{"time":"1609027200","formattedTime":"Dec 27, 2020 \u2013 Jan 2, 2021","formattedAxisTime":"Dec 27, 2020","value":[61],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["61"]},{"time":"1609632000","formattedTime":"Jan 3 \u2013 9, 2021","formattedAxisTime":"Jan 3, 2021","value":[100],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["100"]},{"time":"1610236800","formattedTime":"Jan 10 \u2013 16, 2021","formattedAxisTime":"Jan 10, 2021","value":[97],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["97"]},{"time":"1610841600","formattedTime":"Jan 17 \u2013 23, 2021","formattedAxisTime":"Jan 17, 2021","value":[61],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["61"]},{"time":"1611446400","formattedTime":"Jan 24 \u2013 30, 2021","formattedAxisTime":"Jan 24, 2021","value":[60],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["60"]},{"time":"1612051200","formattedTime":"Jan 31 \u2013 Feb 6, 2021","formattedAxisTime":"Jan 31, 2021","value":[53],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["53"]},{"time":"1612656000","fo
```

Comment: check the value of `iot_trimmed`.  I don't think it is what you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

`iot_trimmed = req_json_interest_over_time.text[len(data_trim):]`
is giving you a string (the text part of the `requests.get()` response, with the first part trimmed off.)

Python needs the object to be a `dict` in order to extract a given key from it. It looks like the requests response object has a `.json()` method which gives you a dict.

So try replacing the above line with
`iot_trimmed = req_json_interest_over_time.json()`

Comment: You're right. I'm making it a string to trim the unwanted characters. I didn't even think about that. Thanks guys, all good now.